# me da el error "missing return statement"

Tags: poo, polimorfismo

Me da el error "missing return statement".En net beans me dice que tengo que poner otro return que equivale a 0¿Habra problema si pongo otro return?, porque yo nomas quiero que aparezcan  2 return(el del 10% y del 15%)

```
    public  float calcularPrecioFinal(){
       if(numSillas <= 8){
           return numSillas - 10% precio;
       }else{
        if(numSillas >=10)
            return numSillas - 15% precio;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Tienes una condición dentro del else por lo que aún te quedan casos sin evaluar ( no solamente tienes if y else, básicamente tienes un if y un else if.

Comment: Si `numSillas` es 9, no se ejecuta ningun `return`

Comment: En POO un método es un bloque de código para hacer algo. No te centres en lo que quieres retornar, sino en lo que debe hacer tu método. Verbaliza eso y luego lo plasmas en el código, por ejemplo: *Este método recibe tal valor, debe determinar que si tal cosa ocurre tal cosa, en caso contrario ocurre tal cosa. Al final, retorna tal cosa*. A mi juicio, ese es el principal error aquí: no aparece con claridad lo que debe hacer tu método, y esa es su razón de ser.